# Removing quotes from columns of monetary value from csv file?

Tags: python, csv

Removing quotes from columns of monetary value from csv file?

My CSV:

```
"   2102"|"LINDOMAR MARTINS DE FREITAS"|"RUA 02 NR.270"|"FORMOSA"|"98130860"|"TIMON"|"MA"|"ADMINISTRATIVO"|"FATURISTA"|"LINDOMAR"|"S"|20130102|20130102|20130102|115.00|"TDC"|"4"|"88792334"|""|""|""
```

I want a column with the value `115.00` is without quotes.

```
L = []
reader = csv.reader(open(infile), csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')

for row in reader:
    L.append(tuple(row))
```

In Python List `L` column with the value `115.00` is thereby `'115 .00 '`. I think the method is `csv.header` putting quotes on all columns.

Comment: csv.reader will always read the input as string

Answer (score 2):

You could do just use float on the appropriate column. Note however, that **float is generally not used for currency values due to rounding errors**. Python has a dedicated [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type for this like that, which offer advantages over pure float, notable that:

> ... Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# consider: from decimal import Decimal
from pprint import pprint
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    L = []
    reader = csv.reader(open("infile.csv"), 
        csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        # consider: L.append( tuple( row[:14] + [Decimal(row[14])] + row[15:] ))
        L.append( tuple( row[:14] + [float(row[14])] + row[15:] ))
    pprint(L)
```

Which would yield:

```
[(' 2102',
  'LINDOMAR MARTINS DE FREITAS',
  'RUA 02 NR.270',
  'FORMOSA',
  '98130860',
  'TIMON',
  'MA',
  'ADMINISTRATIVO',
  'FATURISTA',
  'LINDOMAR',
  'S',
  '20130102',
  '20130102',
  '20130102',
  115.0,
  'TDC',
  '4',
  '88792334',
  '',
  '',
  '')]
```

Comment: miku, I have several files. With several columns in different positions. After that want to insert an Oracle database.

Comment: @Ivanelson, well I guess it's just a matter of parameterization. I added an important note to my post regarding floats and currencies.

Comment: Legal. but also a new question. How easily identify which column /position of CSV has value like it 115.00?

Comment: @Ivanelson, that really depends on your data. In the worst case there is no way to recognize what a datum really is. E.g. is 9.58 a currency or the time of the current 100m world record?

Comment: DBAPI should be able to solve it and store the data according to the column type?! I'll search a little more DBAPI.